Is USE INDEX the right solution to speed up my mysql query?
For some reason my mysql query is running very slow and when I ask mysql to explain it, it appears that it isn't using some of my indexes. Can someone help me figure out how to get mysql to use my indexes or speed up this query?
there is a similar question here:MySQL with JOIN not using index But I believe my question is different as the one that i linked to the OP wasn't using indexes on one of their tables, where I am and yet mysql still isn't using them in a way to maximize load time.
if I add use index to my query:
SELECT content.id FROM content USE INDEX(link_id), users 
WHERE link_id = '2220' AND user_id=users.id 
ORDER BY content.id DESC LIMIT 8

it does speed up the query to an acceptable amount. But is there something else I should be doing? Is use index a bandaid covering up an unresolved problem?
Here are my two tables:
Users table:



Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra




id
int(11)
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment


name
varchar(100)
NO
MUL
NULL




id and name both have indexes
Content Table:



Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra




id
int(20)
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment


type_id
int(10) unsigned
NO
MUL
NULL



link_id
int(11)
NO
MUL
NULL



user_id
int(20) unsigned
NO
MUL
NULL




id, type_id, link_id, author_id all have indexes
Here is my query:
SELECT content.id FROM content, users 
WHERE link_id = '2220' AND user_id=users.id 
ORDER BY content.id DESC LIMIT 8

Here is my explain table of the above query:



id
select_type
table
Type
possible keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
extra




1
SIMPLE
users
index
PRIMARY, id
PRIMARY
4
null
332
Using index; Using Temporary; using filesort


1
SIMPLE
content
ref
user_id, link_id
user_id
4
users.id
22
Using index condition; using where



Thanks for your help!

id, type_id, link_id, author_id all have indexes , it's not the quantity of index that matters. Judging from your query, I believe table content would benefit a lot from a composite key (link_id,user_id) . Please add that and check the query explanation again.

I don't see any columns of users being used.  Have you given us the full query?
